# Spacy's Dependency Parser

Tags: spacy, sentiment-analysis

I was trying to play around with Spacy's Dependency Parser to extract Aspect for Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis.
I followed this link: https://remicnrd.github.io/Aspect-based-sentiment-analysis/

When I tried the following piece of the code on my data, I got an Error message.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

dataset.review = dataset.review.str.lower()

aspect_terms = []
for review in nlp.pipe(dataset.review):
    chunks = [(chunk.root.text) for chunk in review.noun_chunks if chunk.root.pos_ == 'NOUN']
    aspect_terms.append(' '.join(chunks))
dataset['aspect_terms'] = aspect_terms
dataset.head(10)
```

The Error message was:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

The Error was in this line:

```
for review in nlp.pipe(dataset.review):
```

Could someone please help me understand the issue here and how to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the solution here incase it helps someone in future.
I was getting the Error because I had some empty rows for the column review.
I re-ran the code after removing the empty rows/rows with NaN values for the column reviews and it works fine :)